# Fail to pass some Gomoku/Caro game test cases

Tags: python, nested-lists, gomoku

This is the question:
Gomoku or Caro is a board game where each player alternatively places a stone of his color at
an empty intersection of the board. A player wins the game if he is the first player who creates
(i) an unbroken line (either horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) of exactly five stones, and (ii) this
line is not blocked at either end by stones of the other player.
We can use a nested Python list to represent a state of the game as in the examples below
is represented by [[“”, “b”, “”, “”], [“”, “b”, “w”, “”], [“”, “”, “”, “”]] where “”, “b”, “w”
represent the empty intersection, the black stone intersection, and the white stone intersection
respectively.
is represented by [[“”, “”, “”, “”, “”, “”], [“”, “b”, “w”, “”, “”, “”], [“”, “”, “b”, “”, “”, “”],
[“”, “”, “”, “w”, “”, “”]]
In this homework, your goal is to check who is the winner of a given game state. More
specifically, your task is to write a function named “get_winner” that gets a nested list
representing a Gomoku/Caro game state and returns either “black”, “white”, or “none” if the
black stone player is the winner, the white stone player is the winner, other there is no winner
respectively. Here we assume that there is no case that both players are winners.
This is my case testing result on Gradescope: I passed all the test cases in the given question but failed to pass these 2 test cases which are not mentioned in the question above

Test 10 (0/2)
Test Failed: 'black' != 'none'
-black
+none

Test 11 (0/2)
Test Failed: 'none' != 'black'
-none
+black

I do not know why I failed these test cases and what are these test cases because Gradescope hide them. Does my code satisfy all the requirements of the question and why I fail these two cases? Is there any situation that my code have not fulfilled all the possible cases of this Gomoku game, please help me figure that situation and modify the code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> (ii) this line is not blocked at **either** end by stones of the other player.

This appears to be the problem, your programm only checks if the line is blocked at **both** ends by the other player.
Example:

```py
print(get_winner([
    ["w", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", "b", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", "b", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", "b", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", "b", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "b", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
]))
```

`w` is at one end of the line so this should be `none`, but instead your programm says that black won.
<sub>(this example comes to the same result if you try it horizontally or vertically.)</sub>

Edit:
Also the diagonal checking is not working as expected

```py
print(get_winner([
    ["b", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", "b", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", "b", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", "b", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", "w", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "b", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "w"],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
]))
```

This should certainly say `none` but instead black is the winner, which violates both rules
<sub>this only happens on diagonal lines tho</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have modified my code and passed almost all test cases but only 1 test case failed and I still do not understand why...
That test case 
[['b', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['', 'b', '', '', '', 'w', '', '', ''], 
['', '', 'b', 'w', 'b', '', '', '', ''], 
['', '', 'w', 'b', 'b', '', 'b', 'b', 'w'], 
['', '', 'w', '', 'b', '', '', '', ''], 
['', 'w', 'w', '', '', 'w', '', '', ''], 
['', '', 'w', '', '', '', '', '', '']] 
expected to return "none" but I got "black", do not understand why I failed despite the diagonal line of 5 constant "black" exists.

Comment: @HanhNguyen Without seeing your updated code I can't look into it, if you still need help you can edit your question to include your updated code, but you should be able to figure it out by yourself just keep testing, maybe use a [dubugger](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) or just use a lot of `print` statements like 90% of all python users do xD tho using `print` for debugging is not recommended